# How to pass a callback from .NET Core application to a C DLL

Tags: c#, c, .net-core, garbage-collection, interop

I try to pass a delegate from a .NET core as a function pointer to a DLL with a C interface.

The C function is accepting a function pointer. That will be set as a callback function handle internally.

I get the following error when I try to call the callback function from the C DLL.

"Fatal error. System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt."

Note: The DLL source code can also be edited. The DLL and the .NET Core applications need to work across platforms, hence the requirement of C language instead of C++.

Comment: No-one knows what you have been actually trying and how. You should share your attempt.

Comment: Not sure how you expect us to tell you the problem in your code if we can't see it?

Answer (score 1):

So the problem is you have something like this:

```
[DllImport("C.dll")]
public static extern int SetCallback(Action delegate);
public static extern int PerformAction();
public static extern int ClearCallback(Action delegate);

public void PerformSomeOperation()
{
    SetCallback(HandleEvent);
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        PerformAction();
    }
    ClearCallback(HandleEvent);
}

private void HandlEvent()
{
}
```

The problem is the delegate got garbage collected. The fix for this is to keep the delegate alive:

```
public void PerformSomeOperation()
{
    Action handler = (Action)HandleEvent;
    SetCallback(handler);
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        PerformAction();
    }
    ClearCallback(handler);
}
```

If the callback handler scope is global, keep the delegate in a global variable and clear it immediately after calling `ClearCallback`.

If the callback handler scope is global and the handler is never freed, keep the delegate in a static variable and never clear it.

If the code structure uses a heap-allocated callback manager that still doesn't clear the handler, this can still be done. We just need to keep the delegate alive until we're done using it:

```
[DllImport("C.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr SetupAction(Action delegate);
public static extern int PerformAction(IntPtr ctx);
public static extern int FreeAction(IntPtr ctx);

public void PerformSomeOperation()
{
    Action handler = HandleEvent();
    IntPtr ctx = IntPtr.Zero;
    try {
        ctx = SetupAction(handler);
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            PerformAction();
        }
    finally {
        if (ctx != IntPtr.Zero) FreeAction(ctx);
        GC.KeepAlive(handler);
    };
}

private void HandlEvent()
{
}
```

TL;DR version:

If the handler is work-local and has a clear function, put the delegate in a variable and use the same variable in both set and clear.

If the handler is work-local and has no clear function, put the delegate in a variable, and use GC.KeepAlive to keep it active until after the last place where it can be used.

If the handler is global and has a clear function, keep the delegate in a static variable and clear the delegate variable after calling the clear function.

If the handler is global and has no clear function, keep the delegate in a static variable and never clear it.